# Go closure deadlock

Tags: unit-testing, go, closures

Trying to mock http response in Go test. The code snippet below never terminates if I run it with

> go test example.com/auth/...

```
package auth_test
import (
    "testing"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/http"
)

func TestAuthorization(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("Should return 401 when Gateway returns 401")
    {
        url := oneOffUrlWithResponseCode(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
        response, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)

        if response.StatusCode != http.StatusUnauthorized {
            t.Fatalf("Response should be 401 (Unauthorized)")
        }
    }
}

func oneOffUrlWithResponseCode(responseCode int) string {
    var server *httptest.Server
    server = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        defer server.Close()
        response.WriteHeader(responseCode)
    }))
    return server.URL
}
```

However, if I comment out this line

> defer server.Close()

everything works fine.

Ideally, I do not want to "leak" *httptest.Server outside of oneOffUrlWithResponseCode function and obviously close it after first request.

Why it never terminates? What am I doing wrong? What is the right thing to do?

Comment: Just curious but why do you want to hide the server. It seems pretty reasonable that the server is returned since it is expected to be used for the test eg. server is created and server is closed by the test (instead of in its callback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program doesn't terminate because of a deadlock (and it has nothing to do with closures). You cannot call `Close` inside a handler because internally `Close` waits for all handlers to finish.

The easiest way to fix it is to "leak" httptest.Server outside of oneOffUrlWithResponseCode:

```
func TestAuthorization(t *testing.T) {
    ...
    server := oneOffUrlWithResponseCode(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    defer server.Close()
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", server.URL, nil)
    ...
}

func oneOffUrlWithResponseCode(responseCode int) *httptest.Server {
    return httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        response.WriteHeader(responseCode)
    }))
}
```

Comment: The other alternative I'd like to point out is that the server could be avoid  altogether. The handler could be invokved on a `httptest.ResponseRecorder` and the `http.Request`. Using the `ResponseRecorder`, you can check the `.Code` and see that it should have been updated to `http.StatusUnauthorized` since the code under the test isn't doing much. The only difference is that this is a unit test vs being an integration test.